# no viable constructor copying array element of type 'MyString'

Tags: c++

I was supposed to get a output like this:

```
    1. abcd-efgh-abcd-

    2. abcd-

    3.

    4. abcd-efgh-

    5. efgh-

    6. c

    7. abcd-

    8. ijAl-

    9. ijAl-mnop

    10. qrst-abcd-

    11. abcd-qrst-abcd- uvw xyz

    about

    big

    me

    take

    abcd

    qrst-abcd-
```

So I wrote this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// ------------------MY CODE HERE-----------------
class MyString : public string {
public:
    MyString():string(){}
    MyString(const string &s):string(s){}
    MyString(const char *c):string(c){}
    MyString(MyString &ms):string(ms){} 
    string operator()(int start_, int length_){
        return this->substr(start_, length_);
    }
};
// -----------------------------------------------
int CompareString( const void * e1, const void * e2) {
    MyString * s1 = (MyString * ) e1;
    MyString * s2 = (MyString * ) e2;
    if( *s1 < *s2 )     return -1;
    else if( *s1 == *s2 ) return 0;
    else if( *s1 > *s2 ) return 1;
}
int main() {
    MyString s1("abcd-"),s2,s3("efgh-"),s4(s1);
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
    cout << "1. " << s1 << s2 << s3<< s4<< endl;
    s4 = s3;    s3 = s1 + s3;
    cout << "2. " << s1 << endl;
    cout << "3. " << s2 << endl;
    cout << "4. " << s3 << endl;
    cout << "5. " << s4 << endl;
    cout << "6. " << s1[2] << endl;
    s2 = s1;    s1 = "ijkl-";
    s1[2] = 'A' ;
    cout << "7. " << s2 << endl;
    cout << "8. " << s1 << endl;
    s1 += "mnop";
    cout << "9. " << s1 << endl;
    s4 = "qrst-" + s2;
    cout << "10. " << s4 << endl;
    s1 = s2 + s4 + " uvw " + "xyz";
    cout << "11. " << s1 << endl;
    qsort(SArray,4,sizeof(MyString), CompareString);
    for( int i = 0;i < 4;++i )
        cout << SArray[i] << endl;
    //use string substr(int start,int length); 
    cout << s1(0,4) << endl;
    //use string substr(int start,int length); 
    cout << s1(5,10) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I referenced to several exemplary code, all of which suggested this should work. Yet it turned out that when I tried to g++ this source code, error occurred...

```
maGicZ:PA3 MagicZ$ g++ part_1.cpp 
part_1.cpp:23:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
part_1.cpp:26:27: error: no viable constructor copying array element of type 'MyString'
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
                          ^~~~~
part_1.cpp:11:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        MyString(MyString &ms):string(ms){};    
        ^
part_1.cpp:26:33: error: no viable constructor copying array element of type 'MyString'
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
                                ^~~~
part_1.cpp:11:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        MyString(MyString &ms):string(ms){};    
        ^
part_1.cpp:26:38: error: no viable constructor copying array element of type 'MyString'
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
                                     ^~~~~~~
part_1.cpp:11:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        MyString(MyString &ms):string(ms){};    
        ^
part_1.cpp:26:46: error: no viable constructor copying array element of type 'MyString'
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
                                             ^~~~~~
part_1.cpp:11:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        MyString(MyString &ms):string(ms){};    
        ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```

Tried to figure out this for the whole night, but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `qsort(SArray,4,sizeof(MyString), CompareString);`  No, no, a thousand times, no.  You cannot use `qsort` on a type that is not POD.  Use `std::sort`.  *Tried to figure out this for the whole night, but in vain.* -- The whole issue of using `qsort` was wrong to being with.   You wasted a lot of time using something that wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the `{"string1","string2"}` initializer syntax because you have not defined a move or copy constructor that takes a literal. You should probably make a constructor like

`MyString[] MyStringListCreator(string list[])`

and then use

`MyString list[] = MyStringListCreator({"string1","string2"})`

EDIT: A little more explanation.

So essentially the `"Literal Constructor"` is not defined for `MyString`. So when you say

`MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"}`

you are string to construct a `MyString` with a string literal which is undefined.

The solution I gave is essentially letting you use that list syntax to create a temporaily array of strings and then you define how that works in the function